# Printing a table fro time series on google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, table, chart

I'm quite new to GEE.

I have code that prints a time series of my image collection.

I know that it is possible to download the data to a csv file but is there a way to view my time series data in a table in google earth engine?

I want the data in a table so i can do more analysis on it.

the code to the time series:

```
    //Export 3X3 mean EVI Time Series into a Scatter Chart and a CSV format              
    var TimeSeries = Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
    S2_withEVI_mean, fc, ee.Reducer.mean(), 'EVI', 3, 'system:time_start', fc_ID)
    .setChartType('ScatterChart')
    .setOptions({
      title: 'EVI 3X3 mean Time Series For Shift 1-2 Argentina',
      vAxis: {title: 'EVI'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 4,
      series: {
      }});
// Display.
print(TimeSeries);
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using now or provide a short example of what you mean?

Comment: I edited the code. I want the data as a table and not a time series. A table with the dates and the value of S2_withEVI_mean at each date.

Comment: Use `.reduceByRegion()` to get what you want

Comment: How do I add it to my the code?
There is no .reduceByRegion() in the docs.

Comment: Oh sorry, its `.reduceRegion()`. You then have to use `.map()` to apply this reduction to every image in the collection

Comment: I found the answer. It was so simple.
In the 'setChartType' you need to enter 'Table'